# Count number of selected elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I count the number of elements with the attribute of "selected" if the **selected attribute is added dynamically on click**?

Here is how I'm adding the "selected" attribute:

```
    var $li = $('.swrt_checkbox_button');

    $li.on('click', function(){

        var $el = $(this);
        $el.toggleClass('checkbox-selected');
        $el.attr('selected', function(index, attr){
            return attr == "selected" ? null : "selected";
        });
    });
```

So, what I want to achieve is, if all my elements have the selected attr, then I want to do something, in this case, disable another UI element.

The problem I'm having is this, if I check to see if the attr is selected within the click it works:

```
if($el.is("[selected]")) {
    console.log('yes');
}
```

This logs inside the click function but not outside it. So how can I say:

If all elements have "selected" attr { do stuff }?

Obviously I can't do it within the click because the $el is pointing to "this".

Any help or advice you can offer would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could just get the current count and add one or get the count after you are done adding it.

Comment: $('[selected="selected"]').length

Comment: google jquery select element by attribute

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who commented. Here is what I did to make it work using tymeJV's solution:

```
function addCheck() {

    var $li = $('.swrt_checkbox_button');
    $li.on('click', function(){

        var $el = $(this);
        $el.toggleClass('checkbox-selected');
        $el.attr('selected', function(index, attr){
            return attr == "selected" ? null : "selected";
        });

        var totalElems = $li.length;
        var selectedElems = $('.swrt_checkbox_button[selected]').length;

        if (totalElems == selectedElems) {
            $('.checkboxes-btn').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('.checkboxes-btn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });     
}
addCheck();
```

Probably could be cleaner but it works so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `$li` refers to the entire list, just compare how many have the `selected` attribute:

```
var totalElems = $li.length;
var selectedElems = $('.swrt_checkbox_button[selected]').length;

if (totalElems == selectedElems) {
    //All selected
}
```

You can stick this at the end of your `click` event, so it'll run each time.

Comment: Thanks, that works! The only thing is, if I deselect an item the condition doesn't return to false.

Comment: Never mind, I just added an else statement and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a little line at the ewnd of your click, after activating a selection. Just check if there are any unselected elements left, if not, then run whatever you need.

```
// Check if there are any unselected left.
if(!$('.swrt_checkbox_button:not([selected])').length){
    // Do the all-are-selected thing
}
```

Here's a quick implementation:

```js
$('li').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  if(!$('li:not(.selected)').length) alert('all are selected')
})
```

```css
li {
display: block; widht: 100px; height: 100px;l
}
li.selected { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to not that `selected` is **not** a prop that should be used on `li` elements. Just use a class here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#sel").click(function () {
    $("input:not(:checked)").first().prop("checked", "checked");

    if ($("input[type='checkbox']").length == $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length) {
        alert("All selected :)");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/mm389evr/)